# KeystoneJS: keystone.list is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I want to make a mongoose query from KeystoneJS. Something like below:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Post = keystone.list('Post');

Post.model.find()
    .where('state', 'published')
    .populate('author')
    .sort('-publishedAt')
    .limit(5)
    .exec(function(err, posts) {
        // do something with posts
    });
```

I checked the KeystoneJS v5, list created like:

```
keystone.createList('Post', {
  fields: {
    title: { type: Text },
  },
});
```

If I query like:

```
var Post = keystone.list('Post');
```

I got `keystone.list is not a function`,

anyway to make a KeystoneJS retrieve query results?